# Why TypeScript doesn't produce an error for a function implementation that doesn't match interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the following code:

```
interface Fn {
  (number, string): string;
}

const f: Fn = (v1, v2) => v1;

f(1, 2);
```

I expected TS to emit an error, because if `v1` is `number` and the implementation of the function returns that `v1`, then it means that the function `f` returns `number` type, while the interface says it should return a `string`. But TS doesn't complain. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check this : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGImQbwLAChnIAUIArgLbIBcypZARtADQDOYUVyrUoA5gJTUuvANx4AvnjwIA9iFbIY1dMgC8RAG4BGRsnUAmPqoB8uzaNx4YhbcgDke232FA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface declaration is incorrect. It should have a variable name and its type. In your case number, string are being treated as variables of type `any`

```
interface Fn {
    (v1: number, v2: string): string;
}

const f: Fn = (v1, v2) => v1;

f(1, 1);
```